# Adding Logger debug

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, logging

I'm looking to write each ID I'm going to reboot as I reboot them using a debug output logger.debug("debug output here"). If it does hit an error, it should stop processing the dictionary.

This is what I have but I'm not sure how or where to add the logger debug piece.

```
def reboot(dictionary):
    for w in dictionary:
    intance_client.reboot_instance(RebootInstanceRequest=[{'instanceid':w},])
```